# cut choice parameter value in executable shell script of jenkins

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

I have a choice parameter in Jenkins FreeStyle Job Type.

Choices Are for Variable ${IP}:

```
192.168.1.33-prod
192.168.1.34-qa
192.168.1.35-stage
```

In The Executable Shell Script,I want to remove the the value after "-" in the selected choice parameter, before the value is assigned to the command.

The Command Executed:

```
rsync --owner=ec2-user --group=ec2-user -O --no-p  -arzh --exclude ".git/" --perms --chmod=a+rwx /tmp/some-value/ ec2-user@${IP}:/some-folder/
```

The Linux Command is:

```
echo ${IP} | cut -f1 -d"-"
```

The Result Should be
**Result:**

```
192.168.1.33
```

The Final Command before execution should look like:

However, the value is coming empty when i try the below way:

```
rsync --owner=ec2-user --group=ec2-user -O --no-p  -arzh --exclude ".git/" --perms --chmod=a+rwx $WORKSPACE/ ec2-user@192.168.1.33:/some-folder/
```

Comment: Just use groovy to split the value and extract the IP: `${params.IP.split('-').first()}`

Comment: where do you execute grovy script in jenkins job? @NoamHelmer

Comment: Take a look at the [Groovy Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/), but your sh command for the separation should also work. Can you further explain what is not working?

Comment: Your question lacks some text after `The Final Command before execution should look like:`. The output after `the value is coming empty when i try the below way:` looks entirely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably related to the step where you re-assign the value of the `IP` variable -- that step is missing in your question.

However, in your case it could be more elegant to **use shell parameter expansion** instead of `cut`. With `%%`, you can remove the longest matching pattern at substitution time, so this should do the trick:

```
rsync [...] ec2-user@${IP%%-*}:/some-folder/
```

For details, see [the bourne shell manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sh).